# after using pyinstaller to convert py to exe it doesn't work

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I want to monitor one area but after converting it doesn't work.
There is no message when I used cmd to find some error.
when I start it, it just blink few minutes and then black out.
It work well in python.
please help.
here is the code.

```
import multiprocessing
from re import A
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import time
import threading
from PIL import ImageGrab
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import winsound
from multiprocessing import Process

def screenshot():
 
    pyautogui.screenshot("C:\\Users\\youngseb\\Desktop\\screenshot1.png", region = region1)
    img1 = Image.open("C:\\Users\\youngseb\\Desktop\\screenshot1.png")
    A1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1,lang='kor+eng')
    #print(T)
    strings = A1.split()
    print(strings)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.screenshot("C:\\Users\\youngseb\\Desktop\\screenshot1.png", region = region1)
    img1 = Image.open("C:\\Users\\youngseb\\Desktop\\screenshot1.png")
    A2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1,lang='kor+eng')
    strings = A2.split()
    print(strings)

if (A1 == A2):
    winsound.Beep(2000,500)
    print("ERROR")
else : 
    time.sleep(0.5)
threading.Timer(5, screenshot).start()


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    P1 = Process(target=screenshot)
    P1.start()
    P1.join()


region1 = (572,333,35,15)
```

Comment: How are you running `pyinstaller`? What command, including all of its arguments, do you use to run `pyinstaller`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try running your EXE file from a DOS prompt. Often the error messages will give a clue to what is wrong. You can update your question with the error and we can help you better.